# Vuforia Live Streaming

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, vuforia

I'm using vuforia SDK in IOS for showing video on markers. SDK supports only Local videos because it uses AVAssetReader(it supports only local video) to decode the video. But my requirement is to support live streaming. I'm looking for alternative. How can we decode video without using AVAseetReader??
Can we make use of FFMPeg library to achieve this?? please reply. i'm a new bee.